# Splitting Access DB - can front end users edit the tables in the back end?

Tags: ms-access

Reading a few articles recommending splitting Access DBs under certain circumstances (e.g. [MS Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-an-access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc) ) I am trying to find out which rights front end (FE) user have regarding the back end (BE). I have read that the FE only links to the tables stored in the BE but am not sure what this actually means. Can FE users change records in these tables or are they "read only" within the FE and can only be changed when opening the BE? Is there a difference between this and manually linking a table from one Access DB to another or is it basically the same?

I would need users to be able to update tables in the BE by uploading .csv or .txt files and also by updating individual records. Is this in line with the idea(s) behind splitting a DB?

Answer (score 0):

Linked tables are read-write if the BE file is read-write with the rights granted to the user.

Also, to attach the BE concurrently, the users must be able to create the lock file, *.laccdb, in the shared folder

Comment: Is my understanding correct that after splitting a DB the FE is nothing more than a DB with some linked tables (connected to the BE)? (i.e. a replication of this setup would be possible by creating two DBs and linking certain tables from one to the other).

Comment: Yes. If you have the need to deploy your application within an organisation, you could study my article [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html).